# How to get the list of languages provided by a plugin

Tags: plugins, language, l10n

I'm creating a new wordpress plugin dealing with the admin languages, and I'm wondering if you know how to get the list of languages provided by a specific wordpress plugin ?

like this one :

`lang_arr = wp_get_languages("plagin-name");`

Comment: Do you mean arbitrary third party plugin that is already installed in the system?

Comment: no I'm talking about coding something like :
`wp_get_languages("plagin-name")`

Comment: _Which_ plugin? Installed? In official repository? Scrambled on the wall somewhere? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to use this PHP function to get the list of files contained in the language directory of the plugin :

```
scandir($plg_dir."/language");
```